# Is entropy of prime numbers smaller?

Tags: prime-numbers, entropy

Seems that [entropy (in information theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29) can be expressed as a measure of how unpredictable is each bit of information.

I have done a little experiment: I've measured entropy of the binary representation of numbers, and averaged the results for primes and composite numbers.

To calculate entropy, I use Shannon entropy, which can be expressed as $-\sum_{i}P(x_i)·log_2 (P(x_i))$.  This relates the appearance of each symbol (0 or 1) with how much it was expected to appear. For example, 5 is `101` in binary, so `1` is expected 2 times and `0` is expected once. From there, $P(0)=1/3$ and $P(1)=2/3$, and the entropy of 5 is 0.918296 bit/symbol.

Here are the results, showing range and average entropy for primes and composites:

```
1-9  Avg:  Primes: 0.4796 bit/symbol (4 items)  Composites: 0.7296 bit/symbol (5 items)
1-99  Avg:  Primes: 0.7795 bit/symbol (25 items)  Composites: 0.8763 bit/symbol (74 items)
1-999  Avg:  Primes: 0.8801 bit/symbol (168 items)  Composites: 0.9210 bit/symbol (831 items)
1-9999  Avg:  Primes: 0.9276 bit/symbol (1229 items)  Composites: 0.9403 bit/symbol (8770 items)
1-99999  Avg:  Primes: 0.9481 bit/symbol (9592 items)  Composites: 0.9541 bit/symbol (90407 items)
1-999999  Avg:  Primes: 0.9580 bit/symbol (78498 items)  Composites: 0.9625 bit/symbol (921501 items)
```

Seems that primes have less entropy than composite numbers. I cannot go any further with my computer but, is there any reason why entropy in prime numbers should follow a particular rule?

(Source available at: https://gist.github.com/jjmontesl/2dcf59267b1a5f3827a4)

Comment: Could you summarize, maybe with a small example or two, how you calculate the entropy of a number?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added information about how I calculated entropy to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  It's possible what you're seeing is actually due to the fact that even numbers are guaranteed to have a $0$ to balance out the lead $1$ while odd numbers are not.  I'd recommend rerunning your program over just the odds, to see what happens.

Comment: I can't make sense of your definition of Shannon entropy. What is the range of $i$? Is it $0$ to $1$? What is the logarithm base? Is it $2$? Would I be right in thinking that your definition always gives a value $\le 1$? Surely large numbers should have bigger entropy?

Comment: @Barry: I think it is more to do with the fact that all numbers with _two or more_ trailing $0$'s are composite.

Comment: Updated question with stats only for odd numbers. Sorry if something doesn't make sense, I'm not a mathematician this is as a hobby. @TonyK, yes you are right: it's a natural logarithm, and *i* range is 0 to 1 (the binary digits). I'm unsure about whether larger numbers should have bigger entropy.

Comment: "yes you are right: it's a natural logarithm": but the base of a natural logarithm is $e$, not $2$.

Comment: I used *e* as base for the logarithms so entropy is measured on that base in the figures above. Shouldn't change the outcome of the experiment, in this case, though.

Comment: It would be better to write explicit units for the entropy, so e.g. the entropy of 5 = "101" is 0.918 bit/symbol = 0.637 nat/symbol = 0.276 ban/symbol = 2.75 bits = 1.91 nats = 0.829 bans. I'm not sure where you got 0.366, by the way.

Comment: @jjmontes, I think there's a bug in your program:  It looks like you're only computing $-P(0)\ln(P(0))$, not $-P(0)\ln(P(0))-P(1)\ln(P(1))$.  That is, I finally figured out that $0.366204=-(1/3)\ln(1/3)$.  This begins to make sense of the averages you're getting, since $-(1/2)\ln(1/2)=0.34657$.  Basically what's happening is that large numbers, whether prime or composite, tend to have half $0$'s in their binary expansion.

Comment: Thank you very much all! Fixed the bug, now using base 2 logs and showing units. I updated the results above (consistent regardless of whether I include odd numbers or not). Actually, entropy seems to be lower in prime numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily explained as this:

**Shannon entropy:**  The distance of an n dimensional rectangular solid object from an n dimensional hypercube of the same circumference.

If you take a close look at the formula of entropy: $-\sum_{i}P(x_i)*log_2(P(x_i))$, you can see that it has a maximum when the probabilities of all $x_i$ are exactly even, in this case it is for $x_1=x_2=1/2$.

**Shannon entropy** is here nothing more than the area of a rectangle with some rearranged sites of a circumference 4, the nearer to a perfect square the bigger will be it's entropy since a square always has the maximal area.

For the general case, **Shannon entropy** is the volume of the n-dimensional hyperrectangle of a circumference $3*2^{n-1}$, the further the arrangement of the sites is apart of a hypercube, the less is the volume and the entropy as such.

Now your question is easy to explain, since binary numbers like $111000, 110100,110010,101100,101010,100110$ can never be a prime number, since they are divisible by 2, while at the same time, the remaining combinations which are not divisible by two: $110001,101001,100101,100011$, can still be composite.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. Though apparently this also happens when using only odd numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The prime number is often stated as $\pi(x) \approx \frac{x}{\log x}$ meaning that the number of primes less than $x$ is that much.

However we can have probabilistic interpretation as $\frac{\pi(x)}{x} = \frac{1}{\log x}$ so the odds of a randomly chosen number at random is $\frac{1}{\log x}$.  But what exactly is $\log x$ it is more or less the **number of digits of $x$** so the prime number basically says:

$$ \mathbb{P}[n \text{ is prime}] = \frac{1}{\#\text{ of digits of }n}$$

Please look at Don Zagier's work in [The First 50 Million Primes](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.1007/BF03039306/fulltext.pdf) where he discusses computer simulations related to the prime number theorem.

Comment: Thanks. From that paper, though, I couldn't really deduce whether Shannon entropy of the of prime numbers up to N should be lower than the entropy of the composites in the same interval, or in general, if my observation is meaningful at all or can be explained :-?.